# What is the average absolute deviation of a multivariate normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, absolute-value, variance, average

What is the [average absolute deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation) of a [multivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution)?

We know that the average absolute deviation (or MAD) of a monovariate [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) of mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ is equal to $\sigma\sqrt{2/\pi}$. Is their any equivalent for the multivariate case?

I think I need it to compute $\sum_{i=1}^n \|\mathbf{x}_i\| = \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{{x_1}_i^2 + \ldots + {x_d}_i^2}$, where $\mathbf{x} = (x_1,\ldots,x_d)^T\sim\mathcal{N}_d(\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\Sigma})$.

For simplicity we can consider $\boldsymbol{\mu}=\mathbf{0}$, $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}=\sigma^2\mathbf{I}$, and $d=2$.

Comment: The special case you ask about is [$\sigma\chi_2$-distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution).

Comment: Si I am looking for the mean of samples drawn from a Rayleigh distribution? We have $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i \sqrt{x_i^2 + y_i^2} = \sigma \sqrt{\pi/2}$ with $x$ and $y$ two variables following a centered normal distribution of variance $\sigma^2$ right?